# Unity: how to embed a VR Cardboard game into a website

Tags: unity-game-engine, three.js, webgl, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

Right now, I think there is not a way to do it within Unity. This is what I have found so far (please, correct me if I'm wrong):

- The most popular VR plugins compatible with Unity for both Android and iPhone are [Durovis Dive SDK](https://www.durovis.com/sdk.html) and [Google Cardboard SDK](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/).
- I have read that most Android phones are compatible with those VR plugins. My experience is that just a few are compatible. Durovis Dive SDK seems to be the most compatible one nowadays. If the Android phone has not gyroscope and the game has the Google Cardboard SDK plugin, the game won't load or crash. If the Android phone has not gyroscope, the game will load but the image will be still when we move the phone.
- Unity 5.3 has been just released. It [includes WebGL support](http://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/Manual/webgl-gettingstarted.html). It [includes VR support](http://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality/vr-overview). [Samsung Gear and Occulus are supported](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/VR.VRDeviceType.html). However, I have not found out anything about the compatibility with others Android or iPhone devices. **Maybe it works** (I have not test it. I have not found somebody who has test it yet).
- [Here there is a list with VR technology for the web](https://www.reddit.com/r/WebVR/comments/3ihttg/web_vr_software/).
- We can find [stuff to Export an Unity scene to Three.js](https://www.google.es/search?q=export%20unity%20to%20three.js&oq=export%20unity%20to%20three.js). Scripts and animations don't seem to work though.

Answer (score 0):

I just spoke with an industry leader in VR experiences for media companies a couple weeks ago. And his company was one of the first to attempt VR in a web browser through mobile. He said it didn't work very well. He was partially successful, but if his company had problems, I'm guessing it's still a few years off. He said new additions to HTML are coming that will improve this over the next few years.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

could you try [WEBVR](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/systems/webvr-assets-109152)

YouTube Tutorial: [Demo WebVR Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYt0N8JVJSE)

Although it has some defects, but it can serve you for basic applications. I was testing it with 360 videos, this was very heavy for the platform.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [WebXR](https://github.com/De-Panther/unity-webxr-export). But you can't add both SDK at the same time.